# Windows 8 Main monitor marked as secondary

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I recently changed out my main monitor (dvi connected) and now for some reason it has been marked as number two in the display control panel. I also have my TV connected to the HDMI output. When doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> I need to select "Second screen only" to display the picture on my main monitor. Marking the display as primary has made no difference. How do I mark my main monitor as number one so that when I select "PC screen only" the monitor becomes active.